# “STM32CubeIDE” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash. (On Mac)

Tags: macos, stm32cubeide

After installing STM32CubeIDE on Mac, when we double click on the application, the following error gets shown in a popup window:

> “STM32CubeIDE” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Solution:**

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Open the application using `sudo` as follows:

```
$ sudo /Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/stm32cubeide
```

3. Give root password if required.
4. The application opens normally.

Answer (score 3):

The following command in Terminal does also the trick:

```
xattr -c /Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app
```

Comment: So not sure why this is required after a default install... In any case, thanks @Julien D.

Comment: @KevinParker AFAIK this specific issue has been fixed by STMicroelectronics for a while. It’s a different story for the "unknown developer" Gatekeeper error which requires ST to sign and notarize the app. An Apple process known to be complicated and sometimes impossible to complete.